# Writing a better method with default options and a block in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arguments, block

I have a method in Ruby (a rails helper) that I would like to write better, it's a method that takes a lot of options as a hash, and if those options are not there it has some defaults too.

It currently looks like this:

```
def some_html_helper(options = {}, &block)
    option1 = options.fetch(:option1, "default option1 value")
    option2 = options.fetch(:option2, "default option2 value")
    option3 = options.fetch(:option3, "default option3 value")
    option4 = options.fetch(:option4, "default option4 value")
    option5 = options.fetch(:option5, "default option5 value")
    option6 = options.fetch(:option6, "default option6 value")
    "return html with options used here and content... #{capture(&block)}"
  end
```

So it's possible to pass in one or no options and the rest have defaults, like this:

```
<%= some_html_helper option3: "not default value", do %>
  Some content...
<% end %>
```

Is there a better way to write a method like this?

Answer (score 2):

Use keyword parameters with defaults:

```
def m(o1: 42, o2: :foo, o3: :bar, &block)
  puts [o1, o2, o3].inspect
end

m(o3: 3.14)
#⇒ [42, :foo, 3.14]
```

or. alternatively, use double-splat:

```
def m(**options, &block)
  options = {o1: 42, o2: :foo, o3: :bar}.merge options
  puts options.values.inspect
end

m(o3: 3.14)
#⇒ [42, :foo, 3.14]
```